# jfrog repository is uploading javadoc but not downloading

Tags: android, maven, gradle, javadoc, artifactory

we are using jfrog artifactory to upload our libraries to our servers, so developers can download the libraries via maven.

Since our software is closed source, we only want to upload the .aar file as well as the javadoc.

For testing, we also upload the sources.jar, since I read, that it is not possible to get javadoc in the downloaded file without the sources.
On the server we have the aar and the sources.jar and the javadoc.jar

But if we download the aar library via gradle - we dont get any documentation at all.
Somebody having some hints?

Thanks

EDIT:
Android Studio 2.0
Gradle 2.0.0

The gradle file of the application:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
def appArtifactId = 'xxxxx.xxxx.xxx'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../xxxxxxx.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxxxxx'
            keyAlias 'xxxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 22
        versionName "0.9.4"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        multiDexEnabled false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = appArtifactId }
                    //def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-" + "v"+versionName) //"MyAppName" -> I set my app variables in the root project
                    newName = newName.replace("debug", "")
                    //newName = newName.replace("-release", "-release" + formattedDate)
                    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                          'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    // Check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
dependencies {
    compile ("xx.xxxxx.xxxx.libraryname:libraryname:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"){ changing = true }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile "com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.3.1"
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2' // contains @Nullable etc

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.4'

    compile 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:3.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    // for @debuglog
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.9'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


def appArtifactId = 'xxxxx.xxxx.xxx'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../xxxxxxx.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxxxxx'
            keyAlias 'xxxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 22
        versionName "0.9.4"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        multiDexEnabled false
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = appArtifactId }
                    //def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')
                    def newName = output.outputFile.name
                    newName = newName.replace("app-", "$project.ext.appName-" + "v"+versionName) //"MyAppName" -> I set my app variables in the root project
                    newName = newName.replace("debug", "")
                    //newName = newName.replace("-release", "-release" + formattedDate)
                    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newName)
                }
            }
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                          'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
configurations.all {
    // Check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
dependencies {
    compile ("xx.xxxxx.xxxx.libraryname:libraryname:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"){ changing = true }

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile "com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.3.1"
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2' // contains @Nullable etc

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.4'

    compile 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:3.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    // for @debuglog
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.9'
}
// for @debuglog
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'
```

Comment: Do you if gradle is trying to download the javadocs and not finding them or it simply does not try to download the javadocs? this can be either that you deployed the javadocs to the wrong coordinates or that gradle/Android studio does not try to download the javadocs

Comment: I think it is not downloading the javadocs. How can I check, if it is downloading or not to give you more details?

Thanks for answering so far!

Comment: You should look at the gradle build log for requests for the javadoc files (you might need to increase the logging level). In parallel check the Artifactory request log to see if there are any failing requests for javadoc files.

Comment: From the artifactory log I can see, that it is only downloading .pom .aar and -sources.jar

Comment: so, it seems that the issue is with your Gradle build. If you can share it (or the relevant parts), you might be able to get more help

Comment: Thanks @DrorBereznitsky
I edited my initial post with the gradle file.

It is the gradle file of the application, which downloads the library.
There is also a gradle file of the library, which uploads the archive - but that might be not relevant.

Comment: The xml file of the library in the .idea/libraries/MY_LIBRARY shows the following:


   `<JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx/LIBRARY/ed7a7102ad98c33570c959947e1e1b6e12506f93/MY_LIBRARY-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>`


We can clearly see, that there is nothing in the javadoc sections.
I also dont understand, why it does not show the sources since it is properly linked to it...

Comment: It sounds like it is related to android studio more than its is related to gradle